# How can I get one character from cyrillic string c++

Tags: c++

I have wstring with cyrillic word. I need to get one letter from it.
I found only this way:

```
wstring line;
wifstream myfile (".../outfile.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        getline (myfile,line);
        wstring a = line.substr(0,2); // this gives one first letter
       //....
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Are there better ways to get a letter from cyrillic string?

Comment: did you try using an iterator?

Comment: That would depend on the character encoding of the string. (And your loop should be `while (getline(myfile, line)) ...`.)

Answer (score 0):

If cyrillic uses surrogate pairs in UTF-16 encoding, instead of doing this:

```
wstring a = line.substr(0,2);
```

you might want to consider doing something similar to this:

```
const wchar_t surrogate[] = { line[0], line[1], L'\0' };
const wchar_t non_surrogate[] = { line[0], L'\0' };
const wstring a = IS_SURROGATE_PAIR(surrogate[0], surrogate[1]) ?
                  surrogate :
                  non_surrogate;
```

The [IS_SURROGATE_PAIR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318687(v=vs.85).aspx) macro is for Windows - if you are elsewhere you can do the check yourself by reading up on the macro link and on its accompanying [Surrogates and Supplementary Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069(v=vs.85).aspx) docs.